# Need to know the verse numbers from Padma purana

Tags: identification-request, padma-purana

I'd like to know the following 2 shloka's verse number from Padma purana:

> 1. avaiṣṇava-mukhodgīrṇaṁ pūtaṁ hari-kathāmṛtam
>      śravaṇaṁ naiva kartavyaṁ sarpocchiṣṭaṁ yathā payaḥ
>
>    One should not hear anything about Hari from a non-Vaiṣṇava. Milk touched by the lips of a serpent has poisonous effects; similarly, talks about Hari given by a non-Vaiṣṇava are also poisonous.

---

> 2. dvau bhūta-sargau loke'sminn daiva āsura eva ca
>      viṣṇu-bhaktaḥ smṛto daiva āsuras-tada-viparyayaḥ
>
>    There are two classes of men in the created world. One consists of the demoniac and the other of the godly. The devotees of Lord Viṣṇu are the godly, whereas those who are just the opposite are called demons.”

Please someone who is an expert scholar in Sanskrit help me out this chaos.

Comment: This is interesting first half lines are found in one scripture and other half in another scriptures! Btw, I think these verses are quoted in [Shri Radha-Krishna Archana Dipika](https://archive.org/details/rkad_srijiva_pure) by Jiva Goswami

Comment: These verses are missing in the present available versions of the Padma Purana. However, it is definitely possible these verses existed in the Padma Purana during the times of the Goswamis.

Comment: Dear Pandya prabhu, Thank you for your replay. I'm so sorry I could not read Sanskrit or Hindi. I have just started to learn Sanskrit. I'd like to read  "Shri Radha-Krishna Archana Dipika by Jiva Goswami" someday.

Comment: Dear  Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury prabhu, Thank you for your reply. So, you mean the Padma purana we have now have is missing  some silokas from original. If so, how tragic!  Then we can't prove the siloka " avaiṣṇava-mukhodgīrṇaṁ pūtaṁ hari-kathāmṛtam
śravaṇaṁ naiva kartavyaṁ sarpocchiṣṭaṁ yathā payaḥ" is from Padma purana, isn't it? And we do not know even the verse number.  I'm writing an article to defeat atheist who do not believe the authority of Veda. It's too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a similar verse is Agni Purana, but the same is not repeated in Padma Purana as per my findings.

Agni Purana, Chapter 383 (last chapter), Verse 12:

> dvividho bhūtamārgoyaṃ daiva āsura eva ca ।
>   viṣṇubhaktiparo daivo viparītastathāsuraḥ ।। 383.12 ।।
>
> There are two courses for beings;- divine and demonic. Constant
>   devotion to god Vishnu is divine and the contrary is demonic.

But the problem is, the same Agni Purana in other chapter says one who sees difference between Trimurtis will go to hell.

Comment: "but not sure if the same is repeated in Padma Purana." In order to answer the question, you should be sure whethe rverse are present in Padmapurana. If you've checked and sure that verse is not present in Padma Purana then mention it in answer by editing otherwise the present form of the answer doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: @Pandya I am of the opinion that may be the person who quoted this in Shri Radha-Krishna Archana Dipika might have quoted from Agni Purana and claimed that this verse are there in the Padma Purana. So I posted an answer here. And I am unable to find this verse in Padma Purana. So if you think this doesn't answer the question, you may delete it.

Comment: Your problem is resolved only when you read sanskrit literally Siva -> one who is blimshless or one without defect (Any verse you take it states Lord Narayana in mukhya artha) reset are amukhya artha.. the same for Brahma ->one who created this brahmanda i.e. Narayana.. so i didnt see any difference now Siva, brahma, Vishnu all are meaning Narayana in Mukhya artha.. The verse in agni purna find difference is valid if you apply the above logic of madhvacharya @SparkSunshine

Comment: Radha-Krishna Archana Dipika says the verse is from Vishnu Dharma and Agni Purana